# Restore data Mongodb from JSON

Tags: mongodb

I have a dump which including 2 files `data.json` and `metadata.json`.
I need restore this data on my local pc, I tried used `mongorestore` tool, but it don't helped me

Comment: You need to find out how this json was created. If some of the BSON representations of the documents are bigger than MongoDB's maximum size (16MB), then you will need to somehow adjust the JSON so the documents are below the max document size. Use mongoimport for json, not mongorestore. Mongorestore is for BSON dumps created by mongodump.

Answer (score 26):

> The [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/) program writes data from a binary database dump
>   created by mongodump to a MongoDB instance. While, [mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/)
>   tool provides a route to import content from a JSON, CSV, or TSV
>   export created by mongoexport, or potentially, another third-party
>   export tool.

You have .json files. So, you can try mongoimport:

```
mongoimport --db <database_name> --collection <collection_name> <path to data.json>/data.json
```

Comment: I tried used `mongoimport` and got error `exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Date expecting integer milliseconds:`

Comment: Have you created these files using mongodump and what command are you using for mongorestore?

Comment: This dump I got from client and I don't know which tool he used.
I run `mongoimport -d test -c collection_name --file /path/to/data.json` 
and get above error

Comment: `mongorestore -d test /path/to/json`

Comment: If your JSON is an array of objects then add  --jsonArray parameter.

Answer (score 4):

if you met `cannot decode array into a D` like me, just add `--jsonArray` to the command,e.g.

```
mongoimport -db <your-db-name> -c <your-collection-name> --jsonArray <your-json-file-path>
```

Comment: This was helpful when restoring a collection with multiple entries, also instead of using the parameter -db I used a connection string as a positional argument like `mongoimport <http://host:port/database> -c <collection-name> --jsonArray <path-to-json>`